# jQuery jqModal full window pop up browser scroll issue

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

Apologies for a lack of code, but basically I am using the jqModal plugin and it's working great, just as expected, however I just a question about it and was hoping someone could shed some light on how I fix my issue please.

Basically, my popup is 100% width and height of the browser, however the browser scrollbar still reflects the height of my original web page and not the jqModal, any ideas on how I can change this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your input Murali but I found another way around it. Basically, I decided to hide the body scrollbar when triggering the popup and then add a scrollbar to the popup div. Upon closing the popup I re-apply the body scrollbar and this is working a treat. Thanks for taking the time to look and answer my question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Changing scroll position while opening the dialog will fix your problem

```
$('dailog-div').dialog(
    autoOpen: false,

        open: function () {
            var scrollPosition = [self.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft, self.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop];
            var html = jQuery('html'); // it would make more sense to apply this to body, but IE7 won't have that       
            html.data('scroll-position', scrollPosition);
            html.data('previous-overflow', html.css('overflow'));
            html.css('overflow', 'hidden');
            window.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0], scrollPosition[1]);
        },
        close: function () {
            var html = jQuery('html');
            var scrollPosition = html.data('scroll-position');
            html.css('overflow', html.data('previous-overflow'));
            window.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0], scrollPosition[1]);
            $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();

        }

    }).dialog('open');
```